# How can a client program convert a given well known service to a corresponding port number?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

One last question from my review. I've been all over the Wikipedia page for TCP and I think this question isn't related to TCP now.

How can a client program convert a given well known service to a corresponding port number (what command is used, and what does the system do to convert the service name)?

Comment: Read [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getservbyname.html).

Answer (score 0):

the getserv* functions are responsable for this, e.g. getservbyname, getservent ..